# Fail to enroll IOS device in WSO2 2.0.1

Tags: ios, user-agent, mdm, wso2-iot

Trying to enroll IOS device (IPhone 6s, ios 9.3) in WSO2 but unfortunately failing. I am using registered csr file and Apple MDM certificate. Followed instructions mentioned in document. Failing at step 2 on IOS device after entering Domain, username and password. On UI, below is the error

> "An unexpected error occured. Please try again."

In Logs I see below errors:

> [2016-05-06 11:54:22,746] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.util.OAuthUtils} -  Error occurred while sending 'Post' request due to failure of server connection
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <10.XXX.XXX.XXX> !=
>
> [2016-05-06 11:54:22,770] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [JAXServlet] in context with path [/ios-enrollment] threw exception
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)

Not sure what's going wrong. Any thoughts?

Note: my IP is masked above replacing my original IP on which WSO2 is running.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have configured the all the config files where the local IP address is used you need to check that and reconfigure all the files to utilize the IP mask or domain you are using.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to follow the steps given [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+iOS+Server+Configurations) in order to configure IOS
   in WSO2 EMM.
2. You need to obtain a singed CSR from WSO2 by following steps provided [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Obtaining+the+Signed+CSR+File)
3. If the server has domain with a SSL certificate from a know CA, all the root and intermediate certificates must be included to the following keystores.

   - wso2carbon.jks
   - client-truststore.jks

NOTE:

> Make sure to Generate the SSL certificate based on your domain/IP address of the WSO2 EMM server runs on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Kachiecx's answer, I assume you are using a self-signed SSL certificate. When creating a SSL certificate, make sure you provide the common name of the certificate to match your IP/hostname. This is mentioned in the doc [1] under step 6. Also make sure, you follow the step given in step 3 of general server configurations[2]

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+iOS+Server+Configurations
[2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+Server+Configurations#GeneralServerConfigurations-Generalserverconfigurations